# NumberFormatException invalid int

Tags: android

this is my saveddata.java page who can I solve
when I want to update data its say number expectation

and data insert but not update

I am trying to take the input values from EditText and I want to save it to SQLite Database. I don't know how to use the logcat [also please explain how can I read the errors from the LogCat].

```
package com.turningpoint.currencycounter;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class saveddata extends Activity{
    DBHelper mydb;
    private ListView obj;
    ListViewAdapter lviewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.saveditem);
    
        ListViewAdapter arrayAdapter;
    
        mydb = new DBHelper(this);
        List<String> friendsnames= mydb.getAllCotacts();
        List<String> friendsnames2= mydb.getAllCotacts2();
    
        String frnames[]=friendsnames.toArray(new String[friendsnames.size()]);
   

        String frnames2[]=friendsnames2.toArray(new String[friendsnames2.size()]);
        arrayAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, frnames, frnames2);
        obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    
        obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int   arg2,long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id_To_Search = arg2;
                List array_list = mydb.getAllCotacts();
                String s = array_list.get(id_To_Search).toString();
             
                Cursor c2 = mydb.getData4(s);
                while (c2.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = c2.getString(0);
                    String code = c2.getString(1);
```

// String code ..give me Number inut Expetation

```
                    int id2 = Integer.parseInt(id);
                    int code2 = Integer.parseInt(code);
                    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                    dataBundle.putInt("id", id2);
                    int update=1;
                    dataBundle.putInt("update", update);
                    dataBundle.putInt("code", code2);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(dataBundle);                   
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), code, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:inputType="number"` in EditText to make sure that the input is a number not a string or a charater like this

```
<EditText
.
.
.
android:inputType="number"
/>
```

Another solution:

Check if it is a number programmatically

```
boolean digitsOnly = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(editText.getText());
```

Read this article. You will know how to use the logcat

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Debugging-Exceptions-within-your-App

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem

```
int code2 = Integer.parseInt(code);
```

this c2.getString(1) could not Int its give me String